# Use of shared counter in Datastore?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I need to maintain the data in hierarchical way. for example we just consider the following names are my property of my table. `AccountNo,ConnectionId,ContractId,InteractionId,book count`

But the structure of that record is like in hierarchical way. Like

One `AccountNo` may have multiple `ConnectionId` as well as
one `ConnectionId` may have multiple `ContractId`, as well as `InteractionId`. One more condition, in InteractionId is having count of number of books. Ok now

`AccountNo1 -> ConnectionId1 -> ContractId1 -> InteractionId1 ->total book count is 10
AccountNo1 -> ConnectionId1 -> ContractId1 -> InteractionId2 ->total book count is 20
AccountNo1 -> ConnectionId1 -> ContractId2 -> InteractionId1 ->total book count is 4
AccountNo1 -> ConnectionId1 -> ContractId2 -> InteractionId2 ->total book count is 67
AccountNo1 -> ConnectionId2 -> ContractId1 -> InteractionId1 ->total book count is 30
.
.
.`

If i want to retrieve the data by using query like 
`where AccountNo = 1 and ConnectionId = 1` It should display 10+20+4+67=101.

If i give query like
`where AccountNo = 1 and ContractId = 2` It should display 4+67.

Like that i want.

My trainer said that i can do this stuff using `shared counter`.But i didn't get the proper idea in that datastore website.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your instructor meant to use *sharded counters*, which is a way to split a counter among several kinds to be able to update it in parallel.

There's an example of [Sharded Counters in Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) that will allow you to understand it better.

Comment: That link is broken, but this one is handy - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sharded-counters-java